# Are these large horizontal wood planks structural in my 1900s home?

Tags: structural, carpentry, remodeling, old-house

I'm currently in the processes of remodeling a home built in 1900 or even earlier. It has balloon framing and true dimensional lumber. I removed the lath and plaster on the walls and behind some of the exterior walls I found large wood planks that run horizontally.

It's not shiplap because there is no tongue and groove, I can see between the cracks and see old insulation.

My intuition tells me they are structural, and are being used as sheathing. However, the exterior of the wall has some wood siding that is about 1/8 to 1/4 inch thick. So I'm not sure if these wood planks are necessary. Is this something that was commonly done at the time to hold in insulation? Or a trick to make it easier to install the lath and plaster?

Can I remove these planks? I would like to put in new wiring and insulation.

[image]

Comment: @knowitall  Op is asking about the 2x8s(1x8s, 1x12s), not the small pieces of lath.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that those planks were purposely added for sheer strength. If you live in a location with high winds and storms then those planks provide lateral resistance against those forces. If your sill or sole plate is anchored to the foundation then additionally you have earthquake resistance. Your house won't readily topple if you remove them but you'll be sorry after a single bad storm.

I would remove them only with the intention of putting them back after routing utilities and adding proper insulation.

It does concern me that there is no sheathing on the outside of your home, only siding. It means that water will have a much easier time infiltrating your wall cavities and will ruin your insulation efforts unless you go with rockwool.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, my thoughts were the wood siding is being used as exterior sheathing but is not as water tight as proper sheathing. There is however another layer of vinyl siding on top of the original wood siding so that's probably why there has been a lack of water damage so far.

Comment: @GaryHoliday If you remove some of those planks on exterior walls of your home and see no water damage nor rot in the cavity then the wood siding + vinyl combo is doing its job =)

Comment: Please check the definition of a sheer wall it is structural and although they are rare in my area there are some, remove the planks and a wind storm may just cause your home to collapse.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks. I'm aware of what a sheer wall is. I assume you dislike the statement "They are unlikely to be structural"?

Comment: @GaryHoliday Please see the important updates I've made to my answer.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for the update, I live in southern Michigan so really no concern for poor weather other than it gets decently cold sometimes. However, I will be re-installing them after I run installation/electric.

Answer (score 0):

The 2x8 feet are most likely to be structural connecting the 2x4" verticals.

They are correctly mounted with 1/4 inch space for wood expansion.

Why else would they be there ?

Wall hanging TV did not exist in 1900.

Comment: Could be an interior finish, hold insulation, maybe wanted the walls facing the road to be solid?

Comment: @GaryHoliday  the 2ft X 8ft are structural, is that exterior faced